# apache/.htaccess: incorrect page does not redirect to custom 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a strange error where my `ErrorDocument 404` in .htaccess is not working properly in all cases.

If I visit a non-existing page I simply get the message `File not found.`.

If tho, I add the `.html` extension, it shows the custom 404 page I created.

```
https://website.com/not-found
```

This link does not work and I simply get the message `File not found.`

```
https://website.com/not-found.html
```

Visiting this link however, I see my custom 404 page.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

    ErrorDocument 404 /app/templates/errors/404.php
    ErrorDocument 403 /app/templates/errors/403.php

    # Block access to hidden files and directories.
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

</IfModule>
```

Basically I strip the extension and that is all. On other websites this code works good, could it be the hosting company the problem ? **Note that I do not have access to the apache config file**.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache "File not found." instead of 404. error document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898054/apache-file-not-found-instead-of-404-error-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first like this to check for existence of `.php` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

In absence of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` it rewrites every non-file and non-directory.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Now my htaccess contains only your code and the ErrorDocument works for .html and for extensionLESS urls, but if I now visit a non existing page with .PHP, the File not found. error appears, so basically is the opposite of before.

Comment: No, it's in the root of the website!

Comment: Also try replacing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` with `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f`